# Why My player character can't change after go to main menu

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have game the name is quiz game RPG, and I have 1 problem with it, the problem is why after pressing to the town(which is the main menu) and change the character, play it again the character is not the current character but previous character, which is the index back to 0.

I have tried to add playerprefs on the start and change index but nothing changed. still back to 0 after that.

**Character select script:**

```
private void Start()
{
    characterSelect = FindObjectOfType<_CharacterSelect>();
    audioManager = FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>();
    selectedCharIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player",0);
    UpdateCharacterUI();
    character = charactersList[selectedCharIndex].Character;
    isSold = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(selectedCharIndex + "IsSold", 0);
    if (selectedCharIndex == 0)
    {
        if (isSold == 0)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(selectedCharIndex + "IsSold", 1);
        }
    }
    CheckStatus();
    CallPlayer();
}

public void CallPlayer()
{

    currentCharacter = Instantiate(character, new Vector3(-2.403f, -0.6f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
}

private void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine(SaveCharacter());
}

void CheckStatus()
{
    moneyAmount = (int)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("MoneyAmount");
    isSold = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(selectedCharIndex + "IsSold", 0);
    if (moneyAmount >= 0)
    {
        buyButton.interactable = true;
    }
    else
    {
        buyButton.interactable = false;
    }
    if (isSold == 1)
    {
        buyButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        buyButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    Debug.Log(moneyAmount);
    Debug.Log(isSold);
}

public void LeftArrow()
{
    moneyAmountText.text = moneyAmount.ToString() + "$";
    audioManager.play("SFX");
    selectedCharIndex--;
    if (selectedCharIndex < 0)
    {
        selectedCharIndex = charactersList.Count - 1;
    }
    CheckStatus();
    UpdateCharacterUI();

}

public void RightArrow()
{
    moneyAmountText.text = moneyAmount.ToString() + "$";
    audioManager.play("SFX");
    selectedCharIndex++;
    if (selectedCharIndex == charactersList.Count)
    {
        selectedCharIndex = 0;
    }
    CheckStatus();
    UpdateCharacterUI();
}

public void Buy()
{
    audioManager.play("Unlocked");
    moneyAmount -= 0;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(selectedCharIndex + "IsSold", 1);
    buyButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("MoneyAmount", moneyAmount);
    moneyAmountText.text = moneyAmount.ToString() + "$";
}
IEnumerator transition()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    Price.text = "Sold!";
}

public void Confirm()
{
    audioManager.play("Confirm");
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player", selectedCharIndex);
    Debug.Log(string.Format("Character{0}:{1} has been choosen", selectedCharIndex, charactersList[selectedCharIndex].CharName));
    character = charactersList[selectedCharIndex].Character;
    ChangeCharacter();
}

void ChangeCharacter()
{
    Vector3 currentPosition = currentCharacter.transform.position;
    Destroy(currentCharacter);
    currentCharacter = Instantiate(character, currentPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    cameraFollow = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<CameraFollow>();
    cameraFollow.GetPlayer(currentCharacter);
}

IEnumerator SaveCharacter()
{
    if (saveChar)
    {
        saveChar = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        currentCharacter = Instantiate(character, new Vector3(-2.47699f, 0.169f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        cameraFollow = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<CameraFollow>();
        cameraFollow.GetPlayer(currentCharacter);
    }
}
}
```

**For the levelManager:**

```
prvoid Start()
{

    _CharacterSelect = FindObjectOfType<_CharacterSelect>();
    audioManager = FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>();
    selectLevel = FindObjectOfType<SelecLevel>();
    gameManager = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
    FillList();
}
void FillList()
{
    Index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < selectLevel.Levels; i++)
    {
        LevelButton levelButton = Instantiate(TheButton, Spacer).GetComponent<LevelButton>();
        levelButton.LevelIndex = Index;
        levelButton.button.onClick.AddListener(() => SelectLevel(levelButton.LevelIndex));
        Index++;
    }
}

void DeleteAll()
{
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
    Application.LoadLevel(0);
}

void SelectLevel(int index)
{
    _CharacterSelect.saveChar = true;
    selectLevel.levelIndex = index;
    Application.LoadLevel("Level " + (index + 1));
    switch (selectLevel.levelIndex)
    {
        case 1:
            audioManager.StopPlay("BGM");
            audioManager.play("BGM1");
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
    }
}


public void ReseData()
{

    DeleteAll();
}
}
```

**the last GameManager :**

```
private void Start()
    {
        audioManager = FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>();
        //questionManager = FindObjectOfType<_questionManager>();
        LevelSelect = FindObjectOfType<SelecLevel>();
        Select = FindObjectOfType<_CharacterSelect>();
        sliderChanges = FindObjectOfType<SliderChanges>();

        onlepel = LevelSelect.levelIndex + 1;
        IndexLevel = LevelSelect.levelIndex;
        getPlayerData();

        Timecount = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("TimeCount");
        category = FindObjectOfType<_questionManager>().category;

        moneyAmount = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("MoneyAmount");


        if (unansweredQuestion == null || unansweredQuestion.Count == 0)
        {
            thisQuestions = category[IndexLevel].questions;
            unansweredQuestion = new List<Question>(thisQuestions);

            //TrueAnswerText.text = "CORRECT";
            //FalseAnswerText.text = "WRONG!";

            //unansweredQuestion = new List<Question>(questions);
        }
        TrueCount = 0;
        if (FactText != null)
            setCurrentQuestion();


    }

    private void Update()
    {
        moneyText.text = moneyAmount.ToString() + "$";
    }
    #region MainQuestion

    public void getPlayerData()
    {
        levelindexPlayerPrefs = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelIndex", 0);
    }

    public void updateLevel(int Index)
    {
        if (levelindexPlayerPrefs < Index)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelIndex", Index);
            levelindexPlayerPrefs = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelIndex");
        }
    }
    public void setCurrentQuestion()
    {

        Scoretext.text = TrueCount.ToString() + " / " + thisQuestions.Length.ToString();
        RandomQuestionIndex = Random.Range(0, unansweredQuestion.Count);
        currentQuestion = unansweredQuestion[RandomQuestionIndex];
        FactText.text = currentQuestion.fact;
        //IsQuestionAvailable = true;
        sliderChanges.TimeRemaining = sliderChanges.TimeMax;
    }

    public IEnumerator TransitionToNextQuestion()
    {
        unansweredQuestion.Remove(currentQuestion);
        answerQuestion = false;
        if (unansweredQuestion.Count == 0 || unansweredQuestion == null)
        {
            count = thisQuestions.Length;

            changeLevel = false;
            thisQuestions = category[IndexLevel].questions;
            unansweredQuestion = new List<Question>(thisQuestions);
            //unansweredQuestion = new List<Question>(questions);
            count++;
            if (count == thisQuestions.Length || CurrentTrueCount == thisQuestions.Length) ;
            {
                Scoretext.text = TrueCount.ToString() + " / " + thisQuestions.Length.ToString();
                changeLevel = true;
                //Objective.SetActive(true);
                StartCoroutine(EndGame());
                Timecount.SetActive(false);
                StartCoroutine(EveryChapter());
            }
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
        setCurrentQuestion();
    }
    public IEnumerator EndGame()
    {
        int Currentstar = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level" + (IndexLevel + 1));
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("MoneyAmount", moneyAmount);
        if (TrueCount < thisQuestions.Length || TrueCount == thisQuestions.Length - 5)
        {
            if (Currentstar < 1)
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level" + (IndexLevel + 1), 1);
            changeLevel = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            Objective.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
            audioManager.play("Stars");
            Star1.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (TrueCount > thisQuestions.Length - 4 || CurrentTrueCount <= thisQuestions.Length - 3)
        {
            if (Currentstar < 2)
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level" + (IndexLevel + 1), 2);
            changeLevel = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            Objective.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
            audioManager.play("Stars");
            Star2.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (TrueCount > thisQuestions.Length - 2 || TrueCount == thisQuestions.Length)
        {
            if (Currentstar < 3)
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level" + (IndexLevel + 1), 3);
            changeLevel = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            Objective.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
            audioManager.play("Stars");
            Star1.SetActive(true);
            audioManager.play("Stars");
            Star3.SetActive(true);

        }
        updateLevel(IndexLevel + 1);
        getPlayerData();
        Debug.Log(levelindexPlayerPrefs);
    }

    IEnumerator EveryChapter()
    {
        Scoretext.text = TrueCount.ToString() + " / " + thisQuestions.Length.ToString();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(7f);
    }

    public void HandleAnswerButton(bool answer)
    {
        //IsQuestionAvailable = false;
        enemyGenerator.SpawnEnemy();
        sliderChanges.TimeRemaining = 0;
        FactText.text = string.Empty;

        if (answer)
        {
            animator[0].SetTrigger("click");
            if (currentQuestion.isTrue)
            {
                TrueAnswerText.text = "CORRECT";
                moneyAmount += .5f;
                answerQuestion = true;
                TrueCount++;
                Isbattle = true;

                //Scoretext.text = TrueCount.ToString() + " / " + thisQuestions.Length.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                TrueAnswerText.text = "WRONG!";
                Debug.Log("Wrong!");
            }
        }

        if (!answer)
        {
            animator[1].SetTrigger("Clack");
            if (!currentQuestion.isTrue)
            {
                FalseAnswerText.text = "CORRECT";
                moneyAmount += .5f;
                Isbattle = false;
                answerQuestion = true;
                TrueCount++;
                Debug.Log("Correct");
                Debug.Log(TrueCount);
                //Scoretext.text = TrueCount.ToString() + " / " + thisQuestions.Length.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                FalseAnswerText.text = "WRONG!";
                Debug.Log("Wrong!");
            }
        }
        Scoretext.text = TrueCount.ToString() + " / " + thisQuestions.Length.ToString();
        //StartCoroutine(TransitionToNextQuestion());
    }
    #endregion


    #region Panels
    public void Paused()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Pause());
        PausePanel.SetActive(true);
    }

    IEnumerator Pause()
    {
        audioManager.play("Confirm");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        audioManager.play("Close");
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        PausePanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void Back()
    {
        audioManager.play("Close");
    }

    public void Confirm()
    {
        audioManager.play("Confirm");
    }

    public void Dead()
    {
        sliderChanges.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        DeadPanel.SetActive(true);
        HealthBar.SetActive(false);
        PauseButton.SetActive(false);
        Scoretext.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        GoldField.SetActive(false);
        Select.saveChar = true;


    }

    public void TheOptionPanel()
    {
        audioManager.play("Confirm");
        OptionPanel.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void PG_MainMenu()
    {
        audioManager.play("Confirm");
        PlayGame.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ExitGame()
    {
        audioManager.play("Confirm");
        Application.Quit();
    }
    #endregion

    #region TransitionToNextScene
    public void ToTheTown()
    {
        audioManager.StopPlay("BGM1");
        audioManager.play("BGM");
        audioManager.play("Confirm");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }

    public void NExtLevel()
    {
        LevelSelect.levelIndex++;
        Select.saveChar = true;
        audioManager.play("Confirm");
        onlepel += 1;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Level " + onlepel);
        switch (LevelSelect.levelIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                audioManager.StopPlay("BGM");
                audioManager.play("BGM1");
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restart()
    {
        audioManager.play("Confirm");
        Select.saveChar = true;
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }


    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

solved,
it's confusing me all night though

:'D

but it's because I'm just not setting the playerprefs at Savecharacter line at Character select script

```
selectedCharIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player");
character = charactersList[selectedCharIndex].Character;
```